# Chrome/Firefox set breakpoint on all javascript onclick events at once

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to debug a third-party HTML/Javascript page but I can't easily locate the script entry points to set breakpoints on them.

I want the debugger to break on any element's onclick event handler. At the moment if the page is set up with something like

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = bar;
```

then in general it isn't easy to determine that foo and bar are connected.

So, I want to break on all onclicks, wherever they may be.

Can I do this in Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome:

```
Chrome inspector -> sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints
```

Firefox:
    get [EventBug](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/)

You can read a bit more about eventBug in here: [Using Firefox, how can I monitor all JavaScript events that are fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097234/using-firefox-how-can-i-monitor-all-javascript-events-that-are-fired)