# How to detect input's changes from unexpected mouse actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've an input field I need to validate before sending the form.

So I bind a keyup event on this field, it send a XmlHttpRequest, and then I show the result on my ihm. It works fine.

But modern browsers provide some other way to add information into an input fields:

- It remembers last value and provides them as a dropdown

[image]

- It is also possible to paste from clipboard

I tried various event to detect them, but no one's (keyup exepted of course) were triggered.

```
$('#theForm').on('keyup', '.url', checkUrl);
$('#theForm').on('changes', '.url', checkUrl);
$('#theForm').on('click', '.url', checkUrl);
```

Is it possible to detect these events?

My target browser is Firefox 17.

Comment: try the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)-event

Comment: In chrome, you can monitor triggered events using `monitorEvents` API,but as you asked for firefox, here i found something related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097234/using-firefox-how-can-i-monitor-all-javascript-events-that-are-fired

Comment: no event `changes` it is `change`

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't know the `input` event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect that event by using the `input` event:

```
$('#theForm').on('input', '.url', checkUrl);
```

fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/t8exjuq2/

[image]

Clicking that:

[image]

(submit the input of the fiddle once to get a tooltip)

Edit :: Tested in firefox 22.0 and chrome

Also, please note that the `change` event will listen to almost everything but this.

Final edit ::

About the `paste`, you can detect that event by using.... `paste` :

```
$('#theForm').on('paste', '.url', checkUrl);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/490gz5vy/